# How are clone troopers ranked?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

We've seen in the films, TV shows and games that clone troopers have rankings generally displayed on their armor via colors and accessories. But if all the clone troopers are essentially the same, how do they pick one to be the leader?

Comment: Identical twins can be ranked based on performance..

Comment: But identical twins arent bred to be the exact same. Moreover, identical twins are not clones.

Comment: I thought that clones had different training based on their designated raking (i.e. they were given a raking from birth), but I'm not 100% sure of that

Comment: Are you given the skills and ability at birth, or do you gain them from experience? Unless every single clone experiences every single event the exact same way, they will grow and mature differently. And they will just further diverge as they train.

Comment: @DangerZone Largely the clones do experience every single experience in very very similar ways.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg, similar does not equal exact. Even if a conversation between 2 clones went differently than another 2, it could lead to... well, anything. We don't know, it would be pure speculation and I'm no psychologist. Still, it is unsafe to generalize and say "their experiences were all 'close enough' so they should end up perfectly equal. As we see in the Clone Wars episodes, they clearly develop VERY different personalities."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As we see in episodes of the Clone Wars like [Clone Cadets](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Clone_Cadets), the clones are genetically identical, but they are not all equally skilled.

[Wookieepedia mentions](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Clone_trooper/Canon)

The clones begin training together and will be split up and assigned based on their individual aptitude.

> Clone troopers were subjected to intense combat training exercises in order to prepare them for war. As trainees, they held the rank of clone cadet and were organized into multiple squads for the purpose of learning cooperation and teamwork.

Each clone has the genetic makeup to succeed or fail, but based on training and specific personality, they may advance through the ranks, or fail out of service entirely.

> The clones who failed to complete their training were not allowed to become soldiers. Instead of service in the Grand Army of the Republic, they were given janitorial duties and menial work. The cadets that succeeded were promoted to active duty.

Comment: My problem with this is that what we have here is, in effect, the best possible version of a twin study, which have been used in the past to try and settle the nature/nurture debate. Except in this instance, it appears that neither nature nor nurture have an impact on a person if, when given the exact same upbringing, clones still end up different.

Comment: I find it an endearing thought that individuality will find a way even among clones with the same upbringing :-) Although, even though they go to the same training, sleep in similar accommodation and eat the same food, will their experiences be identical?

Comment: @DrRDizzle - I thought the main means used to settle the nature/nurture debate was *faking* identical twin studies.

Comment: @Oldcat But this is the ultimate control group, and they still end up different.

Comment: In reality, there would likely be little advantage in a clone army over an army made by collecting babies that aren't cloned and raising them as 'supersoldiers', whatever that means.  And when you see stormtroopers actually fight....