# How did some Jango-Fett style of clone troopers get command positions?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith, clones, stormtroopers

In *Star Wars: Revenge of the Sith*, one of the clones is referred to as *Commander* Cody.

The clone-troopers are genetically programmed for certain personality and cognitive traits. Do those traits include leadership abilities for a few?

Or are some promoted into leadership roles after serving in a lower level role?

I thought maybe they were bred and trained for command, but [then this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99514/how-are-clone-troopers-ranked) mentions that those who fail training become janitors. So maybe they have to earn their yellow shoulder patches.

Please provide answers with quotes from canon sources.

Comment: They undergo extensive training on Kamino. Even with clones you're going to get *some* variation so presumably those that display any sort of leadership skills there (or in the field as a result of experience) are going to get promoted

Comment: In a lot of the books, and some of the comics, clones have different variations. ARC Nulls were essentially all Jango, while standard infantry were a lot less aggressive. Some troopers received training from Different Mandalorian or Bounty Hunter instructors, which also could have impacted how they act, which creates differences.
Cody was most likely just trained by a harder instructor resulting him being better then other Infantry.

Comment: They were bred for different positions. Every person in the army isn't an on the ground soldier. There are plenty of deck officers and logistics guys and pilots and other jobs -- commander is just one of them.

Comment: @EwokSniper If you can write up your comment as an answer with quotes from sources, I can upvote it.

Comment: Not a full answer, just a hint: my sister and I are not interchangeable.

Comment: Why do you assume that only some of them were given leadership traits? Why not all of them? Of course, the structure of the army is such that only a small proportion of them will lead at any given time, but it's nice to have backup leaders close at hand when you need them. "Every clone trooper has in his pouch a field marshal's baton", and all that.

Answer (score 3):

The clone troops who were to be given leadership positions received extra training just like those who were to be placed in a special unit with special duties.

This is exactly what the Star Wars the Clone Wars series explains. Especially in season 3 episode 1 - Clone Cadets.

Otherwise you can read here with more links to Canonical Information:
https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Clone_trooper

Comment: Could you [edit] in some of the relevant information and quotes from the mentioned episode? That would back this up with evidence and make it a nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

Differences In Clones Due to Instructors/Field Experience/Etc.

Let's start with instructors- for this i'm going to use 'Republic Commando, Hard Contact' as an example.

To start off with, there are multiple times the clones in the story discuss their purpose. One of the Main Characters, A republic commando by the name of Darman, Is waiting after the battle of geonosis for his squad, which turns out to have all been killed in action. Forced to take the last transport back, he has a short winded discussion with a Infantry Soldier, where the Standard infantryman, bred specifically for fighting large land battles envies his upgraded weapons.
Darman stops to think later

> "They don't train like us. They don't fight like us. They don't even
>   talk like us."

So, this can lead us to believe that clones are more or less trained specifically for their position.

Next up we have field Promotions, or just promotions in general. In some of the visual dictionaries, It is stated that the Kaminoans looked for clones that exhibited certain abilities, and they were taken in for specific units, such as starfighter pilots, armor specialists and bomb squad units.

Individual training- Again, going back to Republic Commando. It goes in the story that the special units were trained by well known bounty hunters and other mandalorians. Some of the ARC Nulls,(The Best of the Best, clones so dangerous, they were essentially raw Jango. They pretty much didn't answer to anyone but themselves, and in a comic I can't remember the name of, they take one out of actual cryostasis during an invasion of Kamino. Instead of allowing the Separatists to take the cloning facility, he has dying orders from jango to blow the place to hell instead of ever allowing it to be captured. In the end he doesn't, but this just goes to show how genetically independent clones were due to how they were bred and who they were trained by.

Last but not least, We can take example from SWTCW S7. The Bad Batch, These guys are black ops. troops. Independant, only called in if there is an extremely dirty job. Because of their genetic  mutations, they are much more capable then standard troops, and can do pretty much any job.

Basically it boils down to genetics, and how they were bred for the position. Some of it may be to do with outside fores such as specific trainers, or how well they did in action, but a lot of it is based on how they were bred.

Just remember- It's nothing like the simulations.